# TextView: Remove spacing and padding on top and bottom

Tags: android, android-activity, android-linearlayout, textview

I have one textview which size is 50 dp. I got this result like the picture below.[image] 
I want to remove bottom spaces in my textView ,because its height depend on the text size. And I  want to receive background only into my quotation mark.
Is there any way to remove the unused spaces in my textView?

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="“"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arialbd"
                android:background="#ff0"
                android:textColor="#E8E9EF"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:textSize="50dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:text="“"
    android:fontFamily="@font/arialbd"
    android:background="#ff0"
    android:textColor="#E8E9EF"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:gravity="top" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works on my case. To remove bottom padding. Set the `layout_height` the same size as your `textSize` or 1dp or 2dp less.
Set `includeFontPadding="false"`. Set `android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to implement custom textView. check [this example](https://github.com/suragch/AndroidFontMetrics) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

U can try setting your bottom margin to a negative value.

Something like this:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
```

Let me know if its works, that is the simplest way but can be anothers...

Comment: Negative margin is a bad practice I think.